# PHP monitor VPN connection

Tags: php, snmp

I have a a sonicwall nsa 4500 and i would like to monitor the vpn tunnels on it. Is this possible? I have walked the snmp and I didn't see anything that was related to VPN tunnels. Anyone have ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to verify - you walked the Sonicwall Enterprise MIB (ie, starting with .1.3.6.1.4.1.8741) ?  What you want is most likely to be there (if it exists).